# Making small changes to scss files via FTP without having to re-upload all files

Tags: sass

Please don't shoot me if this is a stupid question. My sass workflow looks like this. I navigate to the directory I'm working in and use the command `sass --watch .` to get it to watch the current directory. Then I usually separate my files into partials and import them into a main file. Once I'm happy with the changes I upload everything to the server.

Now however, I find myself in a situation where I want to make a quick visual change to something on my live site. Normally in CSS I would just download the style.css file make the change and re-upload it. The only way I could see this working in SASS is downloading all my scss files, typing in the `sass --watch .` command again, making that small change and then re-uploading everything via FTP.

Is this the only way? Is there an easier solution?

Comment: Do you need to use FTP?

Comment: I don't need too... It's just what I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just using sass to generate a css file in the command line? If so, you don't even really need to upload the sass files to your server. You can just upload the css file that sass --watch generates.

If you do want the sass files on your server though, you only need to upload the changed sass file(s) and any updated css file(s) that is generated.

If your main file imports _a.sass, _b.sass, and _c.sass and you only make changes to _b.sass, you would only need to upload _b.sass and the css that is generated, but make sure you have fresh copies of _a.sass and _c.sass locally before you make edits.